# undefined local variable or method `arr'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote this mini test-program to save arrays in an array:

```
arr = Array.new

def w(num,text)
  arr << [num, text]
end

w(0123, "was")
w(3453, "hallo")
w(0123, "umbau")
w(0342, "farruko")

arr.each do |f|
 puts f.first.to_s + f.last
end
```

But somehow i get the error:

```
arraytest.rb:5:in `w': undefined local variable or method `arr' for main:Object
(NameError)
        from arraytest.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

What do i wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your code as below if you want to access top level local variable `arr` inside the method `#w`.

```
arr = Array.new

define_method(:w) do |num,text|
  arr << [num, text]
end

w(0123, "was")
w(3453, "hallo")
w(0123, "umbau")
w(0342, "farruko")

arr.each do |f|
 puts f.first.to_s + f.last
end
# >> 83was
# >> 3453hallo
# >> 83umbau
# >> 226farruko
```

`def` creates a new scope, so the local variable `arr` you are seeing inside the method `w`,is scoped only to that method. The top level local variable `arr` is different than the one inside the method `w`. Now if you want to use that outside local variable `arr`, use [`Module#define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method), which supports block. In Ruby blocks are closure so you will be having access to the surroundings.

Comment: Soory but one more question! Is it possible that when i pass the number `0123` it stays as a decimal digit and not as `83` ?

Comment: It's not a good idea to promote the use of `define_method` with a lambda in this case. It may cause several memory issues if you are not aware of how a lambda is and how it works. In fact, it may prevent garbage collection. Bottom line, if you simply need to define a method, use the classic method definition, no need for fancy metaprogramming.

Comment: Agreed, this is a prime example of when the language's "let the programmer do whatever he/she wants" flexibility can be royally abused.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti As far as I know that when you want to have access outside variables, which is not possible using `def`, use `define_method`. If not so, tell me or let me know in what situation you should choose `define_method` instead of `def`.

Comment: You don't use `define_method` because you want to access outside variables, this is a very bad reason and a possible code smell. You use `define_method` when you are dynamically and programmatically defining methods. But in this case you are not, you know the method you want, thus it totally does not make sense.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti You don't then other use of `#define_method`. Which is what I answered... At least I read that Paolo's book.

Comment: Not in this case, it totally does not make sense. The issue is that the user had no clue about scopes, the solution of using `define_method` does not teach him the proper use of scopes, just gave him a solution that could possibly be abused. Again, I told you why, but in order to understand it you need to know how garbage collector works in Ruby and you should care about writing good Ruby code, not only code that works.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Yes.. That's how I write it.. at least in this case..The video you linked.. is no way talked this usage is bad.. that discussion was different..I watched it..

Answer (score 2):

You defined `arr` as a variable

```
arr = Array.new
```

but the variable is not visible inside the scope of the `w` method. The first time you call the method, you get the error.

```
w(0123, "was")
```

If you want to edit `arr`, you need to pass it as argument to the function.

```
def w(arr, num, text)
  arr << [num, text]
end
```

You *could* workaround the issue by using a dynamic definition method such as `define_method` passing a lambda, for example

define_method(:w) do |num,text|
      arr << [num, text]
    end

The lambda has access to the surrounding environment, but in most cases this is an issue, not an advantage. The lambda will prevent garbage collection and you may end up with a memory leak very hard to debug.

[This talk from Aaron Patterson](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQtwIwAQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIlYLZO2aRU&ei=gS2sUvqQIYbrywPcyYDABA&usg=AFQjCNFw5iJE0bgd8ZHPzi5g0WWmSJniWA&sig2=_fKXR1RCmBc3OEhVv1aSiQ&bvm=bv.57967247,d.bGQ) has some very interesting (advanced) details.

Bottom line: if you need to define a simple method, pass the value as argument. Don't use fancy metaprogramming, especially if you are new to Ruby and you don't know the difference.

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is not in scope within the method you defined.

You can fix this either by initialising it as a variable within the method scope, or by storing it as `@arr`—an instance variable. Which approach is better depends on the usage scenario.

Note that if you are using an instance variable you can lazily initialise within the method as follows:

```
def w(num, text)
  (@arr ||= []) << [num, text]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Arup's answer is nearly correct, but he missed one important detail.

`Module#define_method` is a `private` instance method, and **can't** be invoked by *current object*(here, `main`).

Therefore, that code will end up generating the error:

```
 undefined method `define_method' for main:Object
```

Solve this problem, by dispatch the method by [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
arr = Array.new

Kernel.send(:define_method, :w) do |num,text|
  arr << [num, text]
end

w(0123, "was")
w(3453, "hallo")
w(0123, "umbau")
w(0342, "farruko")

arr.each do |f|
 puts f.first.to_s + f.last
end
# >> 83was
# >> 3453hallo
# >> 83umbau
# >> 226farruko
```

Comment: I didn't get any error... I ran it and tested also.. It shouldn't throw any error..Yes that method is private method. But if you notice you will find that, call was implicit. And call has been made by the current class, which is `Object`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Hey, I tried it both in irb and by running it as `ruby file.rb`. It gave me same error `undefined method `define_method' for main:Object`. Practically, in a session, you have self as `main` object of class `Object`, upon which `define_method` can't be call. Why will self be `Object` there? :)